# Inheritance of rows in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

I have a table of rows, here is a sample (as hashes):

```
{:id => 8, :n => 774, :inherits_from => [], :properties => ["a", "b", "c"]}
{:id => 9, :n => 915, :inherits_from => [8], :properties => ["d"]}
{:id => 10, :n => 754, :inherits_from => [1, 2], :properties => []}
{:id => 11, :n => 774, :inherits_from => [10], :properties => ["a", "b"]}
```

The idea is that properties can be inherited from other rows:

```
table[:id => 9] #=> {:id => 9, :n => 915, :inherits_from => [8], :properties => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]}
```

Rows can have one or several inheritances, or can have none. There can be many levels of inheritance, i.e., 5 inherits from 2 and 3, 7 inherits from 5 (which means that 7 inherits from 5, but also from 2 and 3, because 5 inherits from them) etc.
I know I could do it with brute force (i.e., for every queried row check if it inherits from somewhere). Also, I could use Class.new to generate a class for each row and set inheritances (I use ruby), but there will be thousands of rows.

Any advise on how could I do it in the most efficient way?

Comment: This looks like a tree structure (with multiple parents). I think if you search along those lines you'll find some potential solutions.

Comment: `group_by { |row| row[:id] }`